# Downscaling Resolution

Tags: video, resolution

I was wondering if the resolution matters when downscaling. Basically - if I convert 1080p to 480p and 720p to 480p, would the results look the same since they are being downscaled to the same resolution even though they are different resolutions before?

Comment: It depends of the source material.  For example, say you have a line or detail that is one pixel wide in the original.  Going from 720p to 480p, that might still be visible, whereas going from 1080p to 480p it might not.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the scaling algorythm - they would look extremely similar, but probably not bit-for-bit identical.

Some simple math can prove the point.  1080 / 480 = 2.25, while 720 / 480.0 = 1.5 - Thus if the downscaling algorithm takes pixels and averages them out it will get slightly different answers.    Likewise, if it just takes one of the pixels it will sometimes pick a different one.